# Why do I keep on getting null in the console log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, function

In the JS, I am creating an input element which will be nested inside a div with id  "scripts" on the html. I attach a value to that input field via JS and later on I want to catch the value of the input in another JS function. The problem is that when I run the page in the inspect element I can see that there is a value in the input that I created, that input has id "spam_key", but the function that I have created to access and get the value out of the input element is not working properly. If I go to the console, and write console.log(str) I am getting null as result.

Here is what I have in the HTML:

```
<div id="scripts" name="scripts">
    </div>
```

This is the HTML when I run the page and the input field is created:

```
<div id="scripts" name="scripts">
    <input type="number" id="spam_key" value="239">
</div>
```

Now, this is my JS:

```
var c = 0;
var a;
var b;
function counter() {
    return c++;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/...";

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data.data, function (i, obj) {
            //$('#target').append($('<div/>', { id: 'dummy' + i }))
            var text = '<p class="review_text">' + obj.review_text + '</p>'
            var date = '<p class="date">' + obj.created_time + '</p>'
            a = counter();
            $("#carousel").find("[data-index='" + i + "']").append(text, date)

        });
        $('#scripts').append('<input type="number" id="spam_key" value= ' + a + '>');
    });


});
```

And this is what I use to get the value of the input element:

```
var str;
$(document).ready(function () {
    element = document.getElementById('spam_key');
    if (element !== null) {
        str = element.value;
    }
    else {
        str = null;
    }
});
```

Here the value of str should be appled:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("carousel");
    var myHTML = '';
    for (b = 0; b <= str; b++) {
        myHTML += '<div id="review" data-index=' + (b) + '></div>';
    }
    wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML
});
```

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to retrieve the element before you create it?

Comment: EDIT: @kev beat me to it but i'll just leave it here: considering that it returns `null`, and u explicitly sets `str = null` if the element isn't created it could seem that the element might not be created before you call the script the get the value?

Comment: @kev I was thinking about the same thing, but otherwise I have no idea how to get the value of it.. if you have any idea, could you please help me? :)

Comment: @Chri.s yes, probably it searches for the element with id spam_key before it is created.. How can I set to search for the element and get the value of it after the element is created?

Comment: Give me a sec and I'll do something here

Comment: Could you add a sample JSON response from the URL please?

Comment: @JackBashford the JSON response from the html are the reviews from FB page

Comment: @JackBashford there you go, I have put part from the JSON below

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean. Could you please edit your question with a sample JSON response, or provide a link to one.

Comment: @JackBashford the JSON is data from Facebook page reviews, below I have post a comment with part from that data

Comment: Hey Victor, please let me know if the my answer worked for you.

Comment: @ViktorGavrilovic try replacing `$(document).ready(function ()` with `$(window).on("load", function ()` in the part where you get the value

Comment: @Chri.s I have tried that.. it is not working

Answer (score 2):

What I've done is to move the body of your input-retrieval-function from the second `$(document).ready()` to the `callback function` of your `getJSON` method after you've created the `input` element. This way we can make sure to access it after the element is created. I've also added a `var str;` to the global scope where you store the value.

Hope that helps.

```
    var c = 0;
    var a;
    var b;
    var str;
    function counter() {
        return c++;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/...";

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            var items = [];
            $.each(data.data, function (i, obj) {
                //$('#target').append($('<div/>', { id: 'dummy' + i }))
                var text = '<p class="review_text">' + obj.review_text + '</p>'
                var date = '<p class="date">' + obj.created_time + '</p>'
                a = counter();
                $("#carousel").find("[data-index='" + i + "']").append(text, date)

            });
            $('#scripts').append('<input type="number" id="spam_key" value= ' + a + '>');
            element = document.getElementById('spam_key');
            if (element !== null) {
                str = element.value;
            }
            else {
                str = null;
            }
            var wrapper = document.getElementById("carousel");
            var myHTML = '';
            for (b = 0; b <= str; b++) {
                myHTML += '<div id="review" data-index=' + (b) + '></div>';
            }
            wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML       
        });
});
```

Comment: I just tried it, it is not working.. I get null again when i console.log(str)

Comment: Yes, now it is working, but if it I want to use the value of str outside of the $getJSON

Comment: str has been declared globally up on the top, so you shouldn't have a problem with  that.

Comment: I have just updated the code, you can see where I want to access the value of the str. Yes, I know but it is not working.

Comment: when I console.og(str) outside of the $getJSON I get undefined

Comment: I've updated the code to work. A note on using getJSON: This function is asynchronous and that's why it receives an anonymous function to be executed if it succeeded. If you are using console.log in a $(document).ready style str won't be filled because the browser has just started to retrieve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185294/discussion-between-viktor-gavrilovic-and-kev).

Comment: I have run the code that you edited
it is working as I want
it is getting the right value of str and it creates div elements
but there is another problem now
when i am creating div elements, I am creating them inside an owl carousel div, so they get automatically added to an owl carousel
but with this code, they are added inside the div but did not get the owl-item class as well as other things that are important for the owl carousel
and also, this way it is just creating divs
and the divs are not filled with content from the JSON

Comment: I'm new here and don't know the rules very well, but I think you would be better served if you create a new question with all the code and problem described because this question is getting out of the initial scope.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792523/how-to-insert-json-data-to-owl-carousel

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample from the JSON:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "has_review": true,
         "review_text": "Mng sum zadovolna se bese \ud83d\udc4c\ud83c\udffc",
         "recommendation_type": "positive",
         "created_time": "December 6, 2018",
         "open_graph_story": {
            "id": "1924663150981821",
            "message": "Mng sum zadovolna se bese \ud83d\udc4c\ud83c\udffc",
            "start_time": "December 6, 2018",
            "type": "sellers.rates",
            "data": {
               "recommendation_type": "positive",
               "review_text": "Mng sum zadovolna se bese \ud83d\udc4c\ud83c\udffc",
               "is_hidden": false,
               "language": "mk",
               "seller": {
                  "id": "2075976265961628",
                  "title": "My Spa Home & Office Massage - \u041c\u0430\u0441\u0430\u0436\u0430 \u0432\u043e \u0432\u0430\u0448\u0438\u043e\u0442 \u0434\u043e\u043c \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043d\u043e \u043c\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e",
                  "type": "place",
                  "url": "https://www.facebook.com/myspamk/"
               },
               "has_review_update": false
            }
         },
         "has_rating": false
      },
      {
         "has_review": true,
         "review_text": "\u041e\u0434\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u043e \u0438\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e. \u0420\u0435\u0442\u043a\u043e \u0441\u0430\u043a\u0430\u043c \u043c\u0430\u0441\u0430\u0436\u0438, \u0437\u0430\u0448\u0442\u043e \u043c\u0438 \u0441\u0435 \u043d\u0435\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0458\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0438 \u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e, \u043d\u043e, \u043e\u0432\u0430 \u0442\u043e\u043f\u043b\u043e \u0433\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0435\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430\u0447\u0443\u0432\u0430\u043c! \u0411\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043e \u0434\u0435\u0447\u043a\u0438. \u2764",
         "recommendation_type": "positive",
         "created_time": "December 5, 2018",
         "open_graph_story": {
            "id": "1145960125557706",
            "message": "\u041e\u0434\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u043e \u0438\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e. \u0420\u0435\u0442\u043a\u043e \u0441\u0430\u043a\u0430\u043c \u043c\u0430\u0441\u0430\u0436\u0438, \u0437\u0430\u0448\u0442\u043e \u043c\u0438 \u0441\u0435 \u043d\u0435\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0458\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0438 \u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e, \u043d\u043e, \u043e\u0432\u0430 \u0442\u043e\u043f\u043b\u043e \u0433\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0435\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430\u0447\u0443\u0432\u0430\u043c! \u0411\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043e \u0434\u0435\u0447\u043a\u0438. \u2764",
            "start_time": "December 5, 2018",
            "type": "sellers.rates",
            "data": {
               "recommendation_type": "positive",
               "review_text": "\u041e\u0434\u043b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u043e \u0438\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e. \u0420\u0435\u0442\u043a\u043e \u0441\u0430\u043a\u0430\u043c \u043c\u0430\u0441\u0430\u0436\u0438, \u0437\u0430\u0448\u0442\u043e \u043c\u0438 \u0441\u0435 \u043d\u0435\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0458\u0430\u0442\u043d\u0438 \u0447\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e, \u043d\u043e, \u043e\u0432\u0430 \u0442\u043e\u043f\u043b\u043e \u0433\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0435\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0430\u0447\u0443\u0432\u0430\u043c! \u0411\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043e \u0434\u0435\u0447\u043a\u0438. \u2764",
               "is_hidden": false,
               "language": "mk",
               "seller": {
                  "id": "2075976265961628",
                  "title": "My Spa Home & Office Massage - \u041c\u0430\u0441\u0430\u0436\u0430 \u0432\u043e \u0432\u0430\u0448\u0438\u043e\u0442 \u0434\u043e\u043c \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043d\u043e \u043c\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e",
                  "type": "place",
                  "url": "https://www.facebook.com/myspamk/"
               },
               "has_review_update": false
            }
         },
         "has_rating": false
      },
      {
         "has_review": true,
         "review_text": "The best massage in Skopje, highly recommend!",
         "recommendation_type": "positive",
         "created_time": "November 28, 2018",
         "open_graph_story": {
            "id": "10214943185147892",
            "message": "The best massage in Skopje, highly recommend!",
            "start_time": "November 28, 2018",
            "type": "sellers.rates",
            "data": {
               "recommendation_type": "positive",
               "review_text": "The best massage in Skopje, highly recommend!",
               "is_hidden": false,
               "language": "en",
               "seller": {
                  "id": "2075976265961628",
                  "title": "My Spa Home & Office Massage - \u041c\u0430\u0441\u0430\u0436\u0430 \u0432\u043e \u0432\u0430\u0448\u0438\u043e\u0442 \u0434\u043e\u043c \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0440\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u043d\u043e \u043c\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e",
                  "type": "place",
                  "url": "https://www.facebook.com/myspamk/"
               },
               "has_review_update": false
            }
         },
         "has_rating": false
      },
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question with this information?